# How to implement this parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

2 problems when trying to implement this:

- Putting it in the body breaks the sticky nav.
- Scroll bar on div.

If i try to do `http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/` in a div. It causes a scrollbar in that div.

Trying to counter it by putting it in the body directly breaks the sticky nav (made using bootstrap).

Here is the pen `http://codepen.io/dam0/pen/zviHr` that I tried to do also. Similar concept.

I only need a parallax on a div. The different element speed type. Any help?

Here's the [html structure](http://www.hastebin.com/xeguwejuro.django) i have. Please take a look. I already some put comments there.

I'm trying to make it Pure CSS as long as possible. But if it can't be done, help me with js.

EDIT: Added a Pen

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZVEgM
```

Adding the .parallax to the div i want to have a parallax effect causes it to have scrollbar. Putting the parallax class to the body will break the position:fixed of the sticky nav.

EDIT 2: Moved the pen code here

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax holder">
    <div id="carousel" class="parallax__layer parallax__back carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://loremflickr.com/1920/1080/vegetable,healthy,plate" class="img-responsive center-block">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://loremflickr.com/1920/1080/vegetable,healthy,plate" class="img-responsive center-block">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="headerCaption" class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <img src="http://healthyaxcess.ph/img/CaptionBg.png" id="curve" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="navbar-main">
        <div class="container">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://healthyaxcess.ph/img/logo.png"></a>
            </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Sign Up/Login</a></li>
                </ul>

            <!-- Nav links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-section">
                    <li class="current active">
                        <a href="#carousel">First Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-2">Second Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#section-3">Third Section</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dropdown link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- End of navbar collapse -->
        </div><!-- End of Container Fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="container main">
    <div class="text-center" id="section-2">
        <h1>Sample Title</h1>
        <p>The sample title's description here.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:
    .navbar-inverse {
        background: #303030;
    }

```
#navbar-main {
    margin: 0;
}
/* To override the static-top */
#navbar-main.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #navbar-main .navbar-nav {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
}

.main {
/* for example only */
    min-height: 200px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
/* firefox bug fix */
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
/* firefox bug fix */
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#footerBox {
    background-color: #303030;
    color: #FAFAFA;
}

.holder {
    display: none;
}

#headerCaption {
    position: relative;
}

#headerCaption img {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
}

.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.parallax__layer--back {
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

JS:

```
$('#carousel img').on("load", function(){
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-collapse' });
    $('.holder').css('display', 'block');
    $('#nav-wrapper').height($("#navbar-main").height());
    $('#navbar-main').affix( { offset:{ top:$('#navbar-main').offset().top } } );
    $('.carousel').carousel({pause: false});
})
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **must** include a minimal, complete and verifyable example. Links to other sites where your code is pasted (hastebin) are not acceptable. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create one. Please provide a jsfiddle or some form of code sample.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to do now so I asked. If i could do fixed position while in 3d space that would be great but based on my google search and here in SO that's not possible. Tried the backface trick and translatez to 0. It's still not fixing.

Comment: I edited the OP. Please take a look. I provided a PEN.

Comment: @JohnnyDoe please include the code in your actual question rather than linking to it.

Comment: @TylerH I did. I made a pen already. That's my code right there. I just did not put all the contents and they are not part of the parallax problem anyway.

Comment: @JohnnyDoe No, I mean put the actual code in the question here. Check out another random example question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404841/inactive-html-switch-for-visitors

Comment: made another edit @TylerH