# inactive HTML switch for visitors

Tags: html, css, switch-statement

I want to add a HTML switch on my webpage, but, problem is that - I want to see MY status of switcher, so the visitors cant change it, but only see.

I have this:

```css
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 122px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 26px; padding: 0; line-height: 26px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "otevreno";
    padding-left: 12px;
    background-color: #34C258; color: #000000;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "zavreno";
    padding-right: 12px;
    background-color: #D16464; color: #000000;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 5px; margin: 10.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 92px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And my question is: How to make the switcher inactive for visitors, who would be able to see only the status of switcher ("otevreno" or "zavreno") and that only I can edit the status of switcher?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you should just be able to add the `readonly` attribute to the input? Just `readonly`, not `readonly="etc"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `disabled` to your `input` tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" disabled>
```

I have modified the below `background: transparent;` and `border: 2px solid transparent;`

```
.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  margin: 10.5px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 92px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 122px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "otevreno";
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-color: #34C258;
  color: #000000;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "zavreno";
  padding-right: 12px;
  background-color: #D16464;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  margin: 10.5px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 92px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" disabled>
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: One should also **indicate that this button is disabled**, as people will think your site is broken if not, which is never good

Comment: True. But as per the request, I suggested a solution :-)

Comment: Pugazh: yes thats exactly it! Last, maybe stupid question, now, if I want to switch it, I have to rewrite something in code, right? I'm sorry, but I dont know what I should rewrite, Im just an beginner. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Yes. You can add `checked` to your `input` tag. If you remove the `checked` attribute the value will change back.

Eg. `<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" disabled checked>`